# Drawing Gizmo in 3D Viewport while operator's panel is showing?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, operator, gizmo

I'm working in an operator that has as properties a point (Vector) in the 3D space and a radius (float).

I'd like to show in the viewport some kind of circle/sphere with that position and its radius, so the user can see eassily both parameters while they are editing the operator's properties.

I thought about the possibility of adding an empty circle/sphere object when the operators is executed. And then, when the position/Vector (and radius) is edited, in their setter, get that object and move/edit it accordingly the setted values, etc.

But this would require some kind of function that is executed when the operator's panel disappears, so I can delete of that empty object.

Is it possible? Is there any other way to draw those gizmos?

Thank you so much for the help, much appreciated :)

Comment: You may looking for Gpu drawing module: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html

Comment: Thank you so much friend! Looks helpful for my needs!